# Empty AdminHTML Magento Cache Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, cache, grid, ce-1.9.2.3

I have an odd issue where suddenly on my 1.9.3 Magento Community production server the grid items for the **Admin > System > Cache Management** have disappeared.   The same code displays the items fine on my dev and test server.  No errors (or warning) are logged if I turn on developer mode with notices enabled.

See the attached image.[image: empty magento cache grid]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome, and inspect element in this window, go to "Network" , reload, and you search a url like "http://mymagento.com/index.php/admin/cache/index/key/3434152423434" and click to "response", and you catch your error. I have same like problem, hope this help any.

Comment: https://www.maggielouiseconfections.com/index.php/shopadmin/cache/index/key/**ALPHA-NUMERIC-KEY**/ is the page in question so viewing the response is the same as inspecting the source. When you say, "same like problem", do you mean you are experiencing a <div></div> empty grid on that page?

Comment: yes, a javascript file and Layout  "  new varienGrid " , not found in in page, because a bad "Module Rewrite Layout", check layout and javascript file "varien" and the block with  tag html  "id="cache_grid"

Comment: also check "the last patch magento" and "User Pemission" to manage cache